# Facebook Like Button - Social Plugin not functioning

Tags: facebook, widget

I'm running into issues when it comes to the facebook like button plugin.

I'm using the following code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v16.0&appId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&autoLogAppEvents=1" nonce="3YcdPeh8"></script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="page-url" data-width="" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-share="false"></div>
```

What I'm finding is the plugin isn't recognizing if the user is logged into facebook (it'll show the 'sign in' message whether you're logged in or not). Also, once you do log in and click 'like' it doesn't actually do anything - you get a blank popup page and the number of likes isn't changed on the site.

Example here: [https://bangtanweb.net/news/welcome-to-the-grand-opening-of-bangtan-web][1](https://bangtanweb.net/news/welcome-to-the-grand-opening-of-bangtan-web)

I've confirmed that the App ID is set to live. I've also plugged in the URL(s) in the facebook debugger and it all works.

The widget is showing the likes on facebook, but it's not registering the likes if they were triggered on the website.

Unless I'm misinterpreting how the widget works... the user should be able to like the post via the website and it should reflect in the like count correct?